# Is there a way to show a wim file's indexes with commands?

Tags: cmd

I am making a code that shows all wim indexes and export one of them into a single wim file. But my code didn't work as expected. If I use a single wim file than it would work, but if i use a wim that has more than 1 index, than it will be like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQsOO.png)

And here is the code:

```
@echo off
set SRC_PATH=F:\sources\install.esd

:IndexAnalyzer
CLS
ECHO.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A count=0
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i IN ('DISM /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:"%SRC_PATH%" ^| findstr "Index"') DO SET images=%%i
FOR /L %%i in (1, 1, %images%) DO CALL :IndexCounter %%i
ECHO.         The %SRCtype% Image contains the following %images% indexes :
ECHO. 
FOR /L %%i in (1, 1, %images%) DO (
ECHO.  [%%i] !name%%i!
)


:IndexCounter
SET /A count+=1
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%i IN ('DISM /Get-WimInfo /wimfile:"%SRC_PATH%" /index:%1 ^| find /i "Name"') DO SET name%count%=%%j

:ExportSingleIndex
CLS
ECHO.     Please enter the Index number you want to export.
ECHO.
ECHO.     Here are the Indexes :
ECHO.
FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %images%) DO (
ECHO.  [%%i] !name%%i!
)
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P INDEXCHOICE= Your choice : 
pause
```

Comment: add a `goto :eof` to end the subroutine `:IndexCounter` (just before the line `:ExportsingleIndex`)

Comment: Yea now it just displays all index and closes itself

Comment: you need another `goto somewhere` before `:IndexCounter` (probably `goto :ExportSingleIndex`). A label doesn't tell the interpreter to stop, it is just ignored and the next line of code gets executed.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.Haven't thought 'bout it